# SELinux transition from unconfined_r to user_r

Tags: linux, sudo, selinux, access-control

On a Fedora 18 machine, I have the following SELinux context as a regular user created during installation:

```
$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
```

and

```
$ id -Z
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

I want to run a program with the confined selinux role `user_r`, instead of my current `unconfined_r`, so I create a new user with the confined SELinux user `user_r`:

```
# useradd -MN -Z user_u johndoe
# echo 'fubar' | passwd johndoe --stdin
```

Now, I open up a new tty and login as `johndoe` using `agetty`. It complains that `/home/johndoe` does not exist, but essentially, it logs me in. SELinux context:

```
$ id -Z
user_u:user_r:user_t:s0
```

`user_u:user_r:user_t` is perfect and what I want. But I would like to achieve this in a script *already* running as an `unconfined_u` and not as a fresh login. I tried with `sudo`:

If I use `sudo -u`, I get:

```
$ sudo -u johndoe id -Z
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

Which means that the SELinux user doesn't change.

I also tried:

```
$ sudo -r user_r -u johndoe id -Z
sudo: unconfined_u:user_r:user_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 is not a valid context
sudo: unable to execute /bin/id: Invalid argument
```

So, no luck there either.

So how can I transition from the `unconfined_r` role to `user_r`, using `sudo` or `su` (or anything else)?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the policycoreutils-sandbox solution? This is for exactly what you want. For example if you want to execute Firefox in a SELinux restricted environment (unfortunately, but for good reason, "sandbox" is only supported on Red Hat distributions):

```
/usr/bin/sandbox -X -t sandbox_web_t firefox
```

SELinux is set apart from other LSM-based MAC systems by its flexibility and customizability.

This allows you to do what you want, even if it does not make sense. One prerequisite is that you are aware of at least the basic principles and concepts.

There are a couple of things that need to be taken care of here:

- the unconfined_u SELinux identity security identifier must be
  associated with the user_r SELinux role security identifier if you
  want the "unconfined_u:user_r" combination in a security context to
  be valid.

This can be done with:

```
semanage user -m -L s0 -r s0-s0:c0.c1023 -R "unconfined_r system_r user_r" -P user unconfined_u
```

- The unconfined_r SELinux role security identifier must be allowed to
  be manually (via sudo in this case) changed to the user_r SELinux
  role security identifier.

This can be done by creating a simple policy module:

```
cat > myuser.te <<EOF
module myuser 1.0;
require { role unconfined_r, user_r; }
allow unconfined_r user_r;
EOF

checkmodule -M -m myuser.te -o myuser.mod
semodule_package -o myuser.pp -m myuser.mod
sudo semodule -i myuser.pp
```

- Sudo needs to be told which SELinux type security identifier it
  should use together with the specified user_r SELinux role security
  identifier

  sudo -r user_r -t user_t id -Z

I believe i touched on all the consideration but i might have overlooked some and my example may have typo's. Refer to the manual pages for the commands i mentioned.

Comment: `sandbox -t sandbox_min_t id -Z` *does* show that the SELinux role changed to `sandbox_min_t`. I don't know enough about SELinux yet to mark this answer as 'correct', so for now, it gets a +1. Thank you @domg472. I will follow up when I know more.

Answer (score 2):

While using **MLS**, your command

`sudo -u johndoe id -Z`

means that you are passing your **role** and **type** to sudo. You should use the command

`sudo -r user_r -u johndoe id -Z`

Also, if you tried to login with console or ssh you could also see the correct roles and types.

**EDIT:** I want to give some notes too.
You can not change your context (`id -Z`) if there is not a valid transition. You will get error like

`sudo: ... is not a valid context`

For being root, firstly you should be in **sudoers** file and **staff_u** selinux user. For sudo, I like adding only `myuser ALL=/bin/su` for using `sudo su -`. After I did `sudo su -`, became root, I execute `newrole -r sysadm_r` to gain system admin rights. It is not surprising because sudo can not change **role**. As same as, before logging out I execute `newrole -r staff_r` to return my own role. After that I log out, otherwise shell hangs (valid context error).

Answer (score 1):

That's quite tricky. I got something working trough a hack. First, write your script in a file. Then, use `semanage fcontext` to add a labelling rule. SELinux uses this label to apply confinment, somehow. In my example, I'm reproducing postgres context.

```
# semanage fcontext -a -s system_u -t postgresql_exec_t /absolute/path/to/my-script
# restorecon -v my-script
```

SELinux knows some transition. For exemple systemd runs in init_t and file labelled with postgresql_exec_t are transitionned in postgresql context. Thus, I wrote a oneshot systemd service to reuse that transition.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/multi-users.target.wants/my-script.service
[Unit]
Description=My Script
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot

User=postgres
Group=postgres

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/cornac-selinux
```

Then, run it with `systemctl`

```
# systemctl start my-script.service
# journalctl -n 10 --no-pager
août 19 15:19:11 bernace-db0 cornac-selinux[14928]: + id                                                                                
août 19 15:19:11 bernace-db0 cornac-selinux[14928]: uid=26(postgres) gid=26(postgres) groupes=26(postgres) contexte=system_u:system_r:postgresql_t:s0
```

That's the best I can do so far, without writing a custom policy module.